# DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my SQL db, I ran the following script to clean up data and reset the identity columns,

```
-- disable referential integrity
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO

EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'DELETE FROM ?'
GO


-- enable referential integrity again
EXEC sp_MSForEachTable 'ALTER TABLE ? CHECK CONSTRAINT ALL'
GO

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command1 = 'DBCC CHECKIDENT(''?'', RESEED, 1)'
Go
```

I get the following messages,

```
Checking identity information: current identity value 'NULL'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Checking identity information: current identity value '1'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.
Checking identity information: current identity value '1'.....
```

Message being printed for all the tables I guess. Identity has been reset and data has been removed. Do I need to worry about this message?

Comment: `If DBCC printed error messages` -Did it? If it did not, then all is well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
create table t1(col1 int identity(1,1),col2 int)

insert into t1 select 1
insert into t1 select 2
insert into t1 select 3

delete from t1
DBCC CHECKIDENT(t1, RESEED, 1)

Checking identity information: current identity value '3', current column value '1'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

It is just like system predefined message , only the counter will differ( in the example i shown above it is '3'(current identity) and '1'(target identity number))